# vmware dell sensors missing

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell, dell-poweredge, drac

So Im unable to access my idrac via Its IP. I am working remotely so I cant access the server directly. I've also noticed that I am missing a few sensors (I presume this information is supplied by idrac.)

I am running vmware 5.5

Is there any other way to generate a Dell DSET report without access to the idrac or getting sensor data to report?

[iDRAC Post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb84j.png)
[VMware Sensors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE8oQ.png)

Comment: Did you use the dell-specific custom install ISO or the regular vanilla install ISO? You can add in the CIM/hardware sensor drivers later but it's often easier to deploy them up front with the vendor-specific ISO

Answer (score 0):

The other method for collecting a DSET report is to boot the server to the [Support Live Image](http://www.dell.com/support/contents/us/en/19/article/Product-Support/Self-support-Knowledgebase/enterprise-resource-center/Enterprise-Tools/support-live-image). Unfortunately, that won't help you much in this case because:

1. that would require you to be on-site or have iDRAC access, and
2. the information currently missing from esxi02 is only available when the iDRAC is responding.

I'd recommend trying a hard reset on the iDRAC by draining power from the server (unplug, then hold down the power button for ~30 seconds). If it still gives the same error during POST, the iDRAC will probably have to be replaced.